# The record set is not updatable access 2010

Tags: sql, sql-server, forms, ms-access-2010

I am using SQLServer 2012 with my access 2010 project (.adp).  I am wanting to update the information in the following form however when I attempt to make changes I am given the warning 'the record set is not updatable' I created a view in SQL for the form, all my other views and forms in the project update just fine.  I have all the correct permissions.  Is it down to the 'tblEnrolements'?  See the images below to see my database diagram with the relationships set up and also the form I am trying to edit.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had not created a composite key!  Hopefully this will be useful to someone else!
[image]